# How to compare 2 string lists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to compare 2 string lists in SQL, 1 that's held in a DB and one that's an input parameter.

So for background the current SQL states

```
SELECT * FROM Vans WHERE Code = $accountcode
```

Where $code is an input parameter such as 'one,two,three'

An example of Vans is

```
Description, Code, CreatedBy
'VanA','one,two','Matt'
'VanB','one,four','Matt'
'VanC','four,five','Matt'
```

However I now need to edit this to match any item in the Code field in the table to any item in the input string. This needs to be with raw SQL or CTE only (not CLR).

So far I've created a CTE to split the input parameter into a table 'one','two','three' etc - but am not sure of the next step to match to the table string.  I think I need

```
SELECT * FROM Vans WHERE Code LIKE '%one%' OR Code LIKE '%two%' OR Code LIKE '%three%'
```

But I'm unsure how to get there.

So for the example above my code should return VanA and VanB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Storing lists of things is a very bad idea.  You can do what you want with a `split` function (just google "SQL Server split string").  Here is an approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vans v CROSS APPLY
     dbo.split(v.Code) as c(code)
WHERE ','+$accountcode+',' like '%,' + c.code + ',%'
```

Comment: This will not match single items from either list.

Comment: @MattB . . . I fixed the answer, but you have a very, very bad data format.  The codes should be in a separate junction table.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately I inherited it and cannot change it at this time.

Comment: Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Table-valued function 'split' cannot have a column alias.

Comment: @MattB - Come on bro do some **debugging** by yourself too

Comment: @NoDisplayName whilst I could, there seems little point in posting an answer for someone asking a question without testing it first. The very fact I'm asking the question assumes the possibility I don't know how to do this... I'm not a SQL expert hence asking the question. I could spend hours debugging the issue or I could simply focus my time more productively and leave the SQL stuff to someone who knows SQL well. We don't have that in this company so I use my colleagues on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a custom CTE and by fixing the select with CROSS APPLY suggested above.